What would be the meaning/origin of `virtual` in C++?
virtual keyword in C++ sounds bit different from other words like "Virtual Machines", "Virtual Reality".


Virtual base classes make sure only one copy of a base class's member variables are inherited by grandchild derived classes. Wikipedia - Virtual Inheritance
Virtual functions are an inheritable and overridable function or method that is dispatched dynamically. Wikipedia - Virtual Function


Yeah, I understand what virtual keyword does in those two cases. However the meaning of "Virtual" is related with those two cases? Virtual means something "not extisting, not real, happens online/inside computer world" and how is this related to virtual base classes/functions?

Example)
class Interface {
    public:
        virtual void foo() = 0;
};

class Impl: public Interface {
    public:
        void foo() override { ... } 
};

For pure virtual functions,I can see they are "virtual" and derived(or interface implementations) classes should implement those non-existent functions in order to work.
class Animal {
    public:
        virtual void say() { cout << "I'm animal" << endl; }
};

class Dog: public Animal {
    public:
        void say() override { cout << "WOOF" << endl; }
};

But in this case, normal virtual functions, they have original forms(Saying "I'm animal") and derived classes' overriden ones are called dynamically on a runtime, which makes me think the virtual function doesn't look "virtual" to me.

This example is incomplete to show real power of virtual methods. You need something which just uses Interface and calls foo not knowing which implementation it uses. There are many cases where this can be useful. For example dependency injection.

A side note: I think there's no point trying to analyze reserved words in term of their usual linguistic meaning. What's important is to understand their meaning and functionality in the relevant programming language.

For C++ specifically, virtual comes from the Simula language, where Bjarne first learned about classes and member functions.

Example which is more complete and should make this more clear: https://godbolt.org/z/9zraso84M

virtual was sent to earth in a rocket by its father Virtu-El  to escape the destruction of their homeworld Enkryption.

Language-wise, "virtual" as in "seems like something, but isn't": it seems like a member function, but when you call it, you actually end up calling some other function -- but you can't tell.

Don't get your knickers in a bunch about the regular English meaning of the word and its meaning in C++.. sometimes words are used to mean something that's "close enough"

As I understand it, the relevant root is the definition of virtual as "almost but not exactly in every way".  Behaviour of a [non-virtual] member function is determined by the containing class (it is declared as a member of) and data passed to it (via arguments, statics it accesses).  This description is 100% complete for a non-virtual member function, but not for a virtual member function since a derived class may change the behaviour, of the function outside control (or visibility) of the base class.


However the meaning of "Virtual" is related with those two cases?

Both of those cases are typically implemented by having extra indirection.
In a virtual method case, an implementation will have part of each object be a (pointer to a) table of pointer-to-functions corresponding to the virtual member functions, rather than the static addresses of non-virtual member functions that can be embedded at the call site.
In the virtual base case, an implementation will have part of each object be an offset corresponding to the adjustment needed to get a pointer to the virtual base from this, rather than those offsets being a static property of the type. This is also why offsetof isn't valid to use with members of a class with virtual bases.

The table isn’t part of each object. There is one per class.

@user207421 you can do it either way. Importantly the address that is called is looked up at runtime, it isn't baked into the object code
